# Why does the summation of these indicator variables start from i<j?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation, expected-value

I'm currently reading through the eighth edition of  *A First Course in PROBABILITY*, by Sheldon Ross. The section I'm reading is "Momens of the number of events that occur", and I understand everything below except for in the case of the summation of $I_iI_j$, why are they starting from $i<j$?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the summation were over all $i\ne j$, then every pair would be counted twice.

Comment: Are both I's representing events from the same set of events A?